# Which states have the highest percentage of people who qualify for subsidies on the healthcare exchanges?

Tags: united-states, affordable-care-act, us-states

The [Affordable Care Act](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patient_Protection_and_Affordable_Care_Act) allows for taxpayer funded subsidies to purchase health care plans on the exchanges. Households that make less than 400% of the federal poverty level qualify, about $46,000 for an individual or $96,000 for a family of four.

Using 2010 census data,

- Which 10 states have the highest percentage of people who qualify for subsidies?
- What is the average subsidy in those states?

Comment: I'm willing to bet this will correlate with regular poverty statistics, meaning the usual suspects - WV, Lousiana, Mississipi, etc....

Comment: I don't think this data is currently available.  Meaning the administration has yet to release real numbers yet.

Comment: Partial data. https://home.treasury.gov/system/files/131/WP-122.pdf

Answer (score 1):

*Q: Which states have the highest percentage of people who qualify for subsidies on the healthcare exchanges?*

Percent of the Potential Subsidy-Eligible Population Enrolled.

The data in the table is for [2020](https://www.kff.org/health-reform/state-indicator/marketplace-enrollees-eligible-for-financial-assistance-as-a-share-of-subsidy-eligible-population/?currentTimeframe=0&sortModel=%7B%22colId%22:%22Percent%20of%20the%20Potential%20Subsidy-Eligible%20Population%20Enrolled%22,%22sort%22:%22asc%22%7D).

| State | Percent |
| --- | --- |
| Rhode Island | 70.79% |
| Utah | 67.76% |
| Vermont | 65.20% |
| Nebraska | 64.49% |
| Florida | 63.08% |
| Maine | 63.00% |
| California | 58.15% |
| Wisconsin | 52.18% |
| Connecticut | 51.11% |
| New Hampshire | 50.92% |
| Maryland | 49.73% |
| Idaho | 49.56% |

---

*Q: Which 10 states have the highest percentage of people who qualify for subsidies?*

"Estimated Number of Potential Marketplace Enrollees Eligible for Financial Assistance" as a percent of "[Population as of the 2020 Census](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2020_United_States_census#State_rankings)"

| State | Percent |
| --- | --- |
| Florida | 11.12% |
| Wyoming | 10.10% |
| Texas | 10.08% |
| South Dakota | 9.19% |
| North Carolina | 8.69% |
| Mississippi | 8.66% |
| Georgia | 8.57% |
| South Carolina | 8.26% |
| Idaho | 8.07% |
| Utah | 7.90% |

---

"Total Marketplace Enrollees Receiving Financial Assistance" as a percent of "Population as of the 2020 Census"

| State | Percent |
| --- | --- |
| Florida | 7.92% |
| Utah | 5.32% |
| Nebraska | 4.15% |
| North Carolina | 4.12% |
| Wyoming | 3.78% |
| Maine | 3.62% |
| Georgia | 3.56% |
| South Carolina | 3.48% |
| Oklahoma | 3.41% |
| Idaho | 3.36% |

---

*Q: What is the average subsidy in those states?

Not checked.

Comment: I made this a CW should someone wish to answer the other questions.

Comment: I don't think this answer is really responsive. These statistics are the percentage of people who are eligible to enroll who are enrolled which measures state effectiveness in urging eligible people to sign up. The question appears to be asking instead, what percentage of the population of the state is receiving subsidies - a different denominator than the one used in this chart. It is akin to questions about which states are and are not donor states.